# Improving speed of ListBox.SelectedItems.Add

Tags: wpf

This function takes about 3 seconds to reselect 2500 items in ListBox (foreach takes the same time) and blocks the UI during it:

```
private void ReselectFiles(List<FileData> sel)
{           
  FilesListBox.SelectionChanged -= FilesListBox_SelectionChanged;
  for (int i = 0; i < sel.Count; i++)
       FilesListBox.SelectedItems.Add(sel[i]);    
  FilesListBox.SelectionChanged += FilesListBox_SelectionChanged;           
}
```

Is there a way to optimize it?

Comment: hi what do you mean by '3 seconds to "reselect" 2500 items'??

Comment: @Sivasubramanian I mean the previous list of items is stored in a List. Later FileListBox needs to reselect items accoring to that list. FileListBox is bound to ObservableCollection. This function takes 3 seconds to execute if there is 2500 items in passed "sel" list.

Comment: Hi in the for loop each time the count is calculated, instead get the sel.Count in a variable and use it. int fileDataCount = sel.Count(). In for loop use i<fileDataCount. However it will not improve mush performance but its a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Without the details of what FilesListBox actually is it's hard to say, but I am assuming the selected items is bound to an observable collection?

If so, then every time you add an item it will raise a collection changed event which will regenerate the items in the list.

It would be better to derive from ObservableCollection and add some kind of AddRange method - one that blocks the OnCollectionChanged from being called until you have finished adding the items.

An example:

```
public class ObservableCollectionEx : ObservableCollection
{
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        foreach (T item in list)
        {
            this.Items.Add(item);
        }

        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public void ClearAndAddRange(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        this.Items.Clear();

        this.AddRange(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will that actually do it?  Won't calling `this.Items.Add` still fire off the CollectionChanged event?

Comment: @AriRoth Nope.  If you look at the source, you will see the event is raised by the InsertItem override in ObservableCollection.  This is called by ObservableCollection.Add (from the base collection).
By calling Items.Add, the InsertItem is bypassed, meaning no events are raised.

Comment: Yes it is bound to ObservableCollection but this was not the issue as I already had implemented similar (although not this elegant) system to prevent raising events during AddRange